# "NoneType" object has no attribute getitem and python booleans

Tags: python

Edit: i have bypassed the problem by editing the problematic line as this:

```
if ( type(x) == int or ( type(x)==list and type(x[0]) == int ) ) and not ( type(y) == int or (type(y)==list and type(y[0])  == int) ):
```

So in part of my code i am trying to multiply a combination of matrix, integer, or a list-floating point representation(for example [5,9] = 5/9 ). But i get the mentioned error.

My logic is btw, if X (or Y) is NOT a matrix, that means it is either an integer, or it is a [a,b] kind of list which means the first element of it is also an integer, while in matrix it is [ [a,b], [c,d] ] which means first element of X also a list.

Here is the code:

```
def matmult(X,Y):
    #X integer Y matrix
    if ( type(X) == int or type(X[0]) == int ) and not ( type(Y) == int or type(Y[0])  == int ):

        for i in range(len(Y)):
            for j in range(len(Y[i])):
                Y[i][j] = multit(Y[i][j],X)
        return Y
    #Y integer X matrix
    elif ( type(y) == int or type(Y[0])  == int ) and not (type(X) == int or type(X[0]) == int) :

        for i in range(len(X)):
            for j in range(len(X[i])):
                X[i][j] = multit(X[i][j],Y)
        return X
    #both integer
    elif ( type(X) == int or type(X[0]) == int ) and ( type(y) == int or type(Y[0])  == int ):

        return multit(X,Y)
    #both matrix
    else:

        #defining the result matrix
        result = [ [ [] for bim in xrange(len(Y)) ] for bom in xrange( len(X[0]) ) ]
        for i in range(len(result)):
            for j in range(len(result[0])):
                result[i][j] = 0
        #multiplating it    
        for i in range(len(X)):

            for j in range(len(Y[0])):

                for k in range(len(Y)):
                    result[i][j] = sumit( result[i][j], multit(X[i][k],Y[k][j]) )
        return result
```

I get the error for the line:

`if ( type(X) == int or type(X[0]) == int ) and not ( type(Y) == int or type(Y[0])  == int )`:

But probraly i will take it for other cases too.
My take on the issue is that, probably i call X[0] when X may not be a list, but i tough if that is the case and X is integer python would NOT check the other case, since it would stop at "type(X) == int".

This is how i call matmul, i am supposed to get matrix operations in a prefix way btw.

```
if lst[0]=="+":
    return reduce(matsum,lst[1:])
elif lst[0]=="-":
    return matsub(lst[1],lst[2])
elif lst[0]=="*":
    return reduce(matmult,lst[1:])
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mateval.py", line 161, in <module>
    print mateval(["+",["*",["-",1,[1,3]],[[2,[-1,2]],[[7,3],525]],[[7,3],[1,5],-9,23]]]],[[2,3,-1],[[1,2],[1,3],-1]]])
  File "mateval.py", line 150, in mateval
    lst[i] = mateval(lst[i])
  File "mateval.py", line 157, in mateval
    return reduce(matmult,lst[1:])
  File "mateval.py", line 108, in matmult
    if ( type(x) == int or type(x[0]) == int ) and not ( type(y[0])  == int ):
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: If you get an `AttributeError` on that `if` statement, it means that either `X` or `Y` is `None`. How are you calling `matmul`? Also, please paste the full traceback

Comment: This is how i call matmul, i am supposed to get matrix operations in a prefix way btw.

 if lst[0]=="+":
  return reduce(matsum,lst[1:])
 elif lst[0]=="-":
  return matsub(lst[1],lst[2])
 elif lst[0]=="*":
  return reduce(matmult,lst[1:])

Full traceback: Not much of a traceback, just the line i posted with "TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'"

Comment: Please edit your question adding that information :) And you must have a full traceback (something like: `Traceback (most recent call last): File ...`)

Comment: OK, so you call `matmul` via `reduce` and `lst`. Then what's `lst` and how is it generated? That's where your problem lies

Comment: And about the traceback: you must have it, otherwise how do you know which line is giving you the exception?

Comment: Thank you, added it.
lst is a list given me as an input. i failed to see the problem.

Comment: i have bypassed the issue by changing the line as follows:         if ( type(x) == int or ( type(x)==list and type(x[0]) == int ) ) and not ( type(y) == int or (type(y)==list and type(y[0])  == int) ):          . But now i get the same error for another line,        result = [ [ [] for bim in xrange(len(y)) ] for bom in xrange( len(x[0]) ) ]        i will close the question in couple minutes, thank for your help^^ would appriciate if you can see the error in latter line.

Comment: Something (either `matmul` or `multit`) is returning `None`. You have to find out what it is (I cannot: you have not shown me the code)

Comment: @DenizUluğ, if you figured out what was wrong you should add it as an answer as it is completely unclear what solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted isn't the same appearing on the traceback. However, I suspect that `matmul` is returning `None` somehow, and this causes the exception. Perhaps, have you forgot a `return` statement?

Note that `multit` may be the culprit.

Comment: lool thank you so much, just noticed the error. it is so funny that i will explain it here: http://codepaste.net/5qb48x Thanks for your help again.